# Localization of HTML used in ASP.net

Tags: html, localization, internationalization, globalization

I have a asp.net application, which used html templates to generate content and sends this in the email. The code to read the html file is as-

```
 private string LoadHtml(string HtmlFile) {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(asm.GetName().Name +
            "." + HtmlFile);
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(stream);
        string html = r.ReadToEnd();
        return html;

    }
```

Since we are in the process of internationlization, i need to localize the html templates, Can someone help me to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added tokens or strings with %Sample% in my html file and replaced these strings appropriately using ResourceManager.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the msdn page about localisation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx

Comment: The link is about localization of asp.net application, where as my concern is for localization of an html page which is used in my asp.net aaplication.

Comment: I dont think you can localize (correct me if i am wrong) the HTML page itself. What you can do is load a different template based on the current localization. Or add .net components to the page, so that these can be localized